# Programmatically debug an animation code - Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, debugging, animation

I'm having an issue with a simple animation code. It works on other project except this one. I don't know how to debug it since there is no error.

I did try debugging it by using (.backgroundColor and setImage to it, just to see if the UIImageView is there, and it is.)

I have tried to programmatically add it but same thing the animation doesn't show.

Here's my code... this is the version connected to the Interface Builder already:

```
.h file

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *images;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;

.m file

self.images = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: [UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"2.png"], nil];

self.imageView.animationImages = self.images;
self.imageView.animationDuration = 1.0;
self.imageView.animationRepeatCount = 5;
[self.imageView startAnimating];
```

***I'm also sure it is on top of the other views, so it is not being covered by the others.

Is there a way I can debug these method: animationImages, animationDuration, animationRepeatedCount, to actually show if it's working or why it is not working on my app?

Or can you suggest another work around, instead of using this kind of code, use another style such as...? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

You can debug animations in slow mode by setting "Toggle Slow Animations in Frontmost App" in iOS simulator.

You can enable this setting by selecting the simulator, selecting the debug tab of the simulator and selecting 'Toggle Slow Animations in Frontmost App', as shown in the screenshot below

Comment: after enabling above setting your animations will execute in slow motion

Comment: Hi Sanjay, thanks for the reply. The issue is that the animationImages are not even showing at all inside the UIImageView when run in the simulator. I can't use this style to debug the animation this way.